# Adding the data from html.erb file into database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Doing Rails (new to Rails).... and would like to add the fields into the database (which my code is not doing). I have 2 models:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: claims
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  status     :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :claim_items
end
```

and

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: claim_items
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  item_title :string
#  lp_number  :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class ClaimItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :claim
end
```

`ClaimItem` is a single item that contains `lp_number` and `item_title`.
'Claim' represents a storage for `claim_items` and has field `status`.

The problem is a user can select (checkbox) a **`multiple checkboxes`**, and after clicking the 'Submit' button, the `lp_number` and `title` should be stored in the database after method `create` gets executed. But I'm pretty sure I did my `html.erb` file wrong:

```
<body>
        <%= form_for @claim, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
            <h3>Please check the items <br></h3>
            <% @lp_title.each do |lp_number, title| %>
                    <%= check_box_tag "check_box", lp_number, checked = false %> 
                    <%= lp_number + ": "%> <%= link_to title, @lp_image[lp_number]%>
                    <br>
                    <%= select_tag(:user_id,    '<option value="0">---Select a reason---</option>
                                                 <option value="1">Bought by mistake</option>
                                                 <option value="2">Missing parts or accessories</option>
                                                 <option value="3">Didn\'t approve purchase</option>'.html_safe)%>

                    <br>
                        <%= text_area :issue_description, :cols => "100", :rows => "100" %>
                    <br>
                    <br>

            <% end %>
            <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
        <% end %>
</body>
```

Methods **`create`**, **`new`**

```
def new
        @claim = Claim.new

        @lp_title = {}
        @lp_image = {}
        lp = products.each do |product|
                        product.units.each do |unit|     
                            @lp_title[unit.lp] = product.title #stores lp numbers and titles
                            @lp_image[unit.lp] = product.img #stores lp numbers and images
                        end  
                    end
    end

def create 
        @claim = Claim.new(params[:post])
        if @claim.save
            redirect_to :action => 'show'
        else 
            redirect_to :action => 'new'
        end

    end
```

Comment: are you sure your view does not return error? Also please show your `def new`

Comment: I think you are not saving anything on your `claim_items` table

Comment: @Lymuel, exactly.... not sure how

Comment: @Lymuel, `new` added